# Are queries in IBatis precompiled?

Tags: java, mysql, ibatis

We are using Ibatis in our project. When the query executes the first time it's slow. But afterwards, the same set of queries are a bit faster than the first time. So are the queries being compiled the first time they execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iBbatis like any database framework built over JDBC, uses `PreparedStatement` to execute SQL queries. From the [Java JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

> The advantage to this is that in most cases, this SQL statement is
>   sent to the DBMS right away, where it is compiled. As a result, the
>   PreparedStatement object contains not just a SQL statement, but a SQL
>   statement that has been precompiled.

So, if by precompiled, you meant on the database, then, yes, they are.

Comment: So while executing first time, is it being compiling and send it to DBMS? Basically When these Ibatis queries gets compiled either start up or while executing at first time?

Comment: This happens at runtime. The queries are compiled at the DBMS. Every time you call them after the first request, you won't wait for the DBMS to compile your query. They are not "compiled" in Java. Don't confuse Java source code compilation and query compilation in databases.

Comment: How long time the query considered as Precompiled? Till DB server restart?

Comment: @SelvakumarPonnusamy Good question. I would think so. Why would the database delete that compilation?

Answer (score 1):

I will like to add that the compilation phase is one of the main phases of an SQL query execution flow. It just gets compiled and cached once by your db optimizer and subsequent calls will skip the compilation phase.

Comment: How long time the compiled query in cache? Till DB server restart?